# Spark Streaming and Kafka: Best way to read file from HDFS

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, spark-streaming

**scenario**

we expect to receive CSV files (10 MB approx), which are stored in HDFS. The process will then send a message to a Kafka topic (message contains file metadata like HDFS location etc).

A spark streaming job listens to this Kafka topic, on receiving a message it should then read the file from HDFS and process the file.

What is the most efficient way to read the file from HDFS in the above scenario?

**read from Kafka**

```
JavaInputStream<ConsumerRecord<String, FileMetaData>> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(...);
JavaDStream<FileMetaData> files = messages.map(record -> record.value());
```

**option1 - use flatmap function**

```
JavaDStream<String> allRecords = files.flatMap(file -> {
    ArrayList<String> records = new ArrayList<>();
    Path inFile = new Path(file.getHDFSLocation());
    // code to read file from HDFS
    return records;
});
```

**option2 - use foreachRDD**

```
ArrayList<String> records = new ArrayList<>();
files.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
    rdd.foreachPartition(part -> {
        while(part.hasNext()) {
            Path inFile = new Path(part.next().getHDFSLocation());
            // code to read file from HDFS
            records.add(...);
        }
    }
}

JavaRDD<String> rddRecords = javaSparkContext.sparkContext().parallize(records);
```

which option is better?
Also, should I be using the spark context's built-in methods to read the file from HDFS instead of using HDFS Path?

Thanks

Comment: Realistically, Apache Nifi handles these types of use cases better than Spark Streaming. 10 MB files are far too small for optimal HDFS health

Comment: i understand but unfortunately nifi is not part of our stack and this is the scenario we have to deal with. any suggestions?

Comment: Spark Streaming can watch files added into HDFS. That's one way I've done it before, but you can also use Oozie/Cron to schedule a Spark job to periodically scan a configurable HDFS path, so maybe that first Spark job can be modified? But regarding your code, while using foreachPartition is generally better, I don't think option 2 here even works because that ArrayList will not be shared over each executor, and for option 1, I would separate `messages.map(message->hfdsPath).flatMap(hdfsPath->records)` to improve parallelism